# What is this particular syntax called in Scala

Tags: scala

I am surfing through Scala for the Impatient, but unfortunately it assumes previous Java experience and an understanding of how `[T]` is used here:

```
object Iterables {
   def filter[T](unfiltered: Iterable[T], predicate: T => Boolean): Iterable[T] = {...}
   def find[T](iterable: Iterable[T], predicate: T => Boolean): T = {...}
}
```

The syntax for every instance of `[T]` and `T` is quite confusing here. What significance does it have when it's listed directly after the function name, such as `filter[T]`. I understand in the parameters list, we're looking for an Iterable of type `T`. But if T is a type, what does `predicate: T => Boolean` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Type Parametric Methods**

A method in scala can accept one or more `type parameter`s, just like a `class`, `object` or `trait` does.

In this case it means that the same method can be called for a type `T` which can vary from call to call, but that have to be consistent within the definition.

Let's use for example

```
def filter[T](unfiltered: Iterable[T], predicate: T => Boolean): Iterable[T]
```

The method expects you to pass:
 - an `Iterable` of `T`s (`unfiltered`)
 - a function that transforms a `T` to a `Boolean` (`predicate`)
and the result will be another `Iterable` of `T`s.

The method will then iterate on the `unfiltered` object and for each element apply the `predicate`, to decide if it must be filtered or not.

The resulting `Iterable` only contains the elements satisfying the `predicate` (i.e. those `t` for whom `predicate(t)` returns `true`)

You can call filter for any type `T`, with the constraint that it must be consistent fo all parameters and the result type.

**examples**

```
//filtered is List(2,3)
val filtered: Iterable[Int] = filter(List(1, 2, 3), (i: Int) => i > 1) 

//filtered is List("b", "abc")
val filtered: Iterable[String] = filter(List("a", "b", "abc"), (s: String) => s contains "b") 

//filtered is List(Some(1), Some(2))
val filtered: Iterable[Option[Int]] = filter(List(Some(1), Some(2), None), (op: Option[Int]) => op.isDefined)


//you can't call this because T is not the same everywhere it's used
val filtered: Iterable[Int] = filter(List(1, 2, 3), (op: Option[Int]) => op.isDefined)

//this will get you
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int] => Boolean
 required: Int => Boolean
           val filtered: Iterable[Int] = filter(List(1, 2, 3), (op: Option[Int]) => op.isDefined) 

                                                                             ^
```

Answer (score 5):

This declaration:

```
def filter[T](unfiltered: Iterable[T], predicate: T => Boolean): Iterable[T]
```

can be read as follows: for any type `T` this function accepts `Iterable` of that type and a function from that type to `Boolean`. Finally it returns `Iterable` of the same type.

*that type* above basically means: you can call this function with `Iterable[String]`, `Iterable[Date]`, `Iterable[Foo]` - you get the idea. But whichever type you choose, it has to be the same in all places. Thus for example:

```
val result = filter(List("a", "bb", "ccc"), (s: String) => s.length() > 1)
```

is correct. But this isn't:

```
val result: Seq[Int] = filter(List("a"), (s: String) => s.length() > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called a *generic method*.

(a similar feature is also available in java, C#, and C++ (where it is called, *template function*))